# Transition en CSS

Tags: css, css3

Lo que trato de hacer es quede una sombra de fondo que pase de izquierda a derecha. El background lo que hace es darle otro color de fondo, pero en vez de que aparezca , que se mueva.
modifique todo. Ahora hice esto:

```css
.Grupo {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.Grupo:hover {
  background: #C7212F !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="area-vulnerables" class="Grupo">
  <a href="" title="">
    <div class="area-icon">
      Contenido
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Bien, hasta funciona todo bien, pero lo que quiero hacer y no me sale es que la transicion sea de izquierda a derecha. Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: No esta claro lo que preguntas... se un poco mas descriptivo... Que esperas hacer?, como esperas que sea tu animación

Comment: Lo que trato de hacer es quede una sombra de fondo que pase de izquierda a derecha. El **background** lo que hace es darle otro color de fondo, pero envez de que aparezca, que se mueva. Se entiende?

Comment: Creo que entiendo, quieres hacer como esto... http://jsfiddle.net/75Umu/3/ pero con el background, no?

Comment: @AlejoFlorez opino lo mismo

Comment: Claro, pero no lo estoy logrando

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No sé si entendí bien, ¿es esto lo que buscas?:

```css
.Grupo {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, white 50%, red 50%);
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.Grupo:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="area-vulnerables" class="Grupo">
  <a href="" title="">
    <div class="area-icon">
      Contenido
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Si lo que quieres es mantener el degradado entonces puedes hacer (gracias @delCano):

```css
.Grupo {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, white, white, red, red);
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 400% 100%;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.Grupo:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="area-vulnerables" class="Grupo">
  <a href="" title="">
    <div class="area-icon">
      Contenido
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

He aumentado un poco el tiempo del `ease-out` para que se aprecie mejor el efecto.

Comment: Si cambias tu degradado duplicando rojo y blanco (`white, white, red, red`) y aumentas el fondo al `400%` conservas el efecto degradado además del movimiento.

Comment: @delCano cierto, en caso de que se quiera mantener el degradado. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Que interesante efecto, lo propongo como respuesta ;)

Comment: esta muy bueno ese efecto. creo que lo pondré en mis sitios.

Comment: **CUIDADO:** Parece que si pones las propiedades de CSS en otro orden ya no se hace el efecto. **[Ejemplo aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/49u6253j/10/)**.

Comment: A mi también me parece que es la respuesta que el busca.  si es así le invito a marcarla.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Intentas editar propiedades de un background antes de establecerlo, por ello no hace el efecto. Recuerda que CSS es código en cascada.

Comment: Si, chicos es lo que buscaba... muchas gracias y perdon la demora, tenia otro trabajo que terminar... pero muchas gracias a todos